# 'adb devices' says unauthorized in TWRP

Tags: android, android-studio

I am in TWRP recovery, version - 3.0.2-0 (multirom)
Android Version - 5.1.1
OS - Cyanogen 12.1 - YOG4PAS1N0

1.

When I connect my phone via usb and try to run `adb devices`, I get -

```
List of devices attached
624225fe        unauthorized
```

And after that when I try any command, I get error -

```
adb shell
error: device unauthorized. Please check the confirmation dialog on your device.
```

No confirmation is being asked in my phone at this time.

When my device is on (not in recovery) and then when I connect it via usb then everything works fine (drivers already installed in my PC, android debugging enabled in my phone).

When I am in recovery then only it is throwing this error.

Also in the TWRP recovery there is an option of 'Terminal' in 'Advanced' and there I am able to run each command of adb and others.

How TWRP is not able to identify that permission has been granted already for adb.
Is it a TWRP version issue?

2. when I am trying `adb pull /data/data/somefile` when my phone is on (not in recovery), its saying `error: device not found`. Did not get this as I have already used this command many times before also.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

If TWRP (and hence `adbd`) is built correctly as `userdebug`/`eng` build, it should never show `unauthorized` error. You can check the following properties using `getprop`:

```
ro.secure=0
ro.adb.secure=0
ro.debuggable=1
```

If not so, either use `setprop` tool or to make changes permanent, extract TWRP `recovery.img` using image kitchen and change/add the values in `ramdisk/default.prop`.

Sometimes `adb` doesn't work  when MTP is disabled (due to difference of `idVendor` and `idProduct` values). For more details on these values and USB connections behavior, you may check `/init.*usb.*rc` files on your device. Re-enable MTP in mount options or set these properties:

```
persist.sys.usb.config=adb,mtp
sys.usb.config=adb,mtp
```

> No confirmation is being asked in my phone at this time.

Confirmation dialogue only appears in running ROM, not in recovery but you may try to make `adbd` work with authorization. Mount `/data` so that `/data/misc/adb/adb_keys` can be read by ADB daemon. Copy contents of `~/.android/adbkey.pub` (RSA key) from your PC to `adb_keys` on your phone. If file doesn't exist, create one and add public key. But be sure not to overwrite the file if it already contains some key from other PC.

Note that `~/.android/adbkey.pub` is the path for Linux systems. On Windows, key exists at `%userprofile%\.android\adbkey.pub` or in rare cases at `%windir%\system32\config\systemprofile\.android\adbkey.pub`.

After making any changes restart `adbd` and `adb`:

```
~$ adb usb
~$ adb kill-server
```

---

**RELATED:** [Storage location of “adb_keys”](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219320/218526)

Answer (score 4):

### Using TWRP:

You must go to the advanced menu and use the "ADB sideload" functionality. It will allow you to use *adb sideload* commands (which you can use to flash zips). You should not be prompted for fingerprint authorization.

### While phone is ON:

If your phone still doesn't connect while ON, be sure you have gone to the developer settings and enabled adb debug through USB.

### In any case:

When the connection is not working it's always useful to restart the adb server:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

### Final tip:

You can also transfer files from TWRP to your PC, using the built in File Manager.